# DisplayTag: How to iterate over a Map

Tags: java, jsp, hashmap, displaytag, stripes

I have a Map that I would like to iterate over to populate a DisplayTag table. What I'm trying to do is create a separate column for each Map entry. My Map looks like this:

```
Map<String, List<String>> testMap = new LinkedHashMap<String, List<String>>();

// please ignore the bad list creation - just using this to get my point across.
testMap.put("Title 1", {"row 1 value", "row 2 value", "row 3 value"});
testMap.put("Title 2", {"row 1 value", "row 2 value", "row 3 value"});
testMap.put("Title 3", {"row 1 value", "row 2 value", "row 3 value"});
```

I want to end up with a table that has the keyset ("Title 1", "Title 2", etc.) as my column headers, and the associated list as my column data. Is this supported?

Comment: Can't you just use testMap.keyset() to get the set of keys and iterate over this to populate your DisplayTag? Or is your question more specific to what DisplayTags can do?

Comment: I tried that but it didn't allow me to create the table I described in the question, unfortunately. I opted to not use a Map. The folks at DisplayTag really should build support for this, unless there's a technical limitation preventing this feature.

Comment: @AlexGuirguis the Displaytag library hasn't been updated in a really long time.  You could probably make it work with a TableDecorator implementation.